# .Net Core 5.0 Identity Scaffolded Code not working with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I have a .net Core 5.0 MVC app that is currently using Windows Authentication. I wanted to add roles to the application so decided to use the Identity framework and then replicate the users of the site and essentially assign them local roles.

This proved to be very tricky and I've ended up at a halfway house solution where I have a visible authenticated user using Windows Authentication that I can use to access the user and roles tables via the UserManager and RoleManager. However, method decorations do not work with my local roles and also the redirects to files such as AccessDenied within the folders in Areas do not work either.
So

```
var identityUser = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;
        var roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(identityUser).Result;
        var isAdmin = _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(identityUser, "Admin").Result;
        if (isAdmin)
            return Forbid();
```

Gets me

```
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44312/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FHome
```

This is the scaffolded code created in IdentityHostingStartup.cs

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YWAFTraceConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
                .AddDefaultUI();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");                    
            });
        });
    }
```

No combination of path entry for `AccessDeniedPath` seems to work - all I get is a 404 - I can work around the lack of decorations working but really need the access denied page to fire.

This is the structure of my Areas folder

[![Areas Folder Structure][1]][1]

It doesn't work locally using IIS Express nor when deployed on IIS

Comment: Have you enabled windows authentication in IIS server?Like <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />

Comment: Yes I have thanks - I think the issue is that I'm trying to use both WA and Identity together. So I have a User object that has all of the windows account properties and a separate IdentityUser that references my local roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` in `app.UseEndpoints` in `Startup.cs` fixed the issue with the Area pages not being found.

Fixed the controller and method authentication by implementing a custom policy as described in the excellent tutorial [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/11/policy-based-authorization-in-aspnet-core)